# import class priority in scala vs java

Tags: java, scala

I got stuck because of import class problem.
In my case, my class has a dependency with Apache Common `StringUtils`, and there is a same name class(`StringUtils`) in same package. (Main class has a dependency with Apache Common's `StringUtils`, and there is a StringUtils in same package with Main class. But it is compile error)

[image]

I specified apache common's `StringUtils` with import syntax, but It seems shadowed by same package's `StringUtils`.
Is it scala's language spec?

In Java, there is no problem. It works with Apache common's StringUtils.
[image]

Comment: Please, post your code as code, not as photographs of code. This is a site for programmers, not photographers, we want to read and copy&paste and compile and execute and test and debug your code, not critique its use of perspective, shadows, contrast, and color. Photographs of code cannot be read by a visually impaired person, they cannot be searched, they cannot be indexed, they cannot be quoted, they cannot be copy&pasted, they cannot be compiled, they cannot be executed, they cannot be tested, they cannot be debugged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because your compiler uses the closest class it can find to represent `StringUtils`. It can either be the one *you* wrote in your code or the one in `org.apache` but who knows? You yourself may not even be sure at some point! So you have to clarify that.

A class is actually defined using the whole package name and when you do an import it only allows you to use the *shortcut* ie `StringUtils` instead of `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils`.

To counter that problem, several options:

- static import with `import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils._`: here you can directly call the method `isEmpty` but the compiler won't find `StringUtils` per say
- use the whole name in your call: `println(org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.isEmpty(...))` That way, no confusion possible
- in Scala you have the possibility of defining alliasses. To do so, you have two options. Either at import time: `import org.apache.commons.lang3.{StringUtils => ApacheStringUtils}` or in your class: `type ApacheStringUtils = org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils`. For this kind of cases, option "at import time" is slightly more convenient and maybe even more efficient (you may replace the type you defined in your code at Runtime).

I would personnally prefer option 3.1 (when you create an alias at import time). This way, you code is clearer and you can call any function from `StringUtils`.

Answer (score 7):

I suggest that you simple use the ability in scala to create an "alias", like:

```
import users.{UserPreferences => UPrefs}  // import and rename for convenience
```

( from [scala-lang.org](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/packages-and-imports.html) )

In other words: simply avoid the shadowing of that class name, by importing the library class under a different name.

Answer (score 6):

You can use Apache's StringUtils by using the fully qualified name.

```
println(org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.isEmpty(""))
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to import all members of `StringUtils` (something like static import in Java):

```
org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils._
```

Then you'd be able to directly call method:

```
println(isEmpty(""))
```